Snowflake update unknown values in column
I have a table in Snowflake like this:

I need to update columns Velocity & Share_pt based on the logic outlined here:

For Velocity column: for min of row_ts where velocity column is not unknown, update Velocity column values with values from min row_ts value and any unknown values after min row_ts should not be updated

Same for Share_pt column as well.


This logic should work on similar scenarios for the entire table.


Hi - 1) please don't use images, use editable text formatted as tables (so someone can copy your data) 2) "I need... " is not a question, what is the actual issue you are facing that you need help with? 3) Please update your question with the SQL you've managed to write so far and explain precisely what your issue is
